# SQL is not show view combining where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have got a view which combines 3495 closing price records x 28 currency pairs.
The view is written as

```
CREATE FOREXVIEW AS
SELECT AUDCAD.Date, dbo.AUDCAD.[Close] AS AUDCAD, dbo.AUDCHF.[Close] AS AUDCHF....
FROM AUDCAD INNER JOIN AUDCHF ON AUDCAD.Date = AUDCHF.Date INNER JOIN ....
```

So that the result display as follow
[image]

I think the resulting table is pretty big

So I want to carry out a query as
select * from FOREXVIEW where date > '2019-1-1';

SQL's process takes forever. Why is that?
Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Are the JOIN and WHERE condition columns indexed?

Comment: Show us the explain/execution plan output. (Or similar. Which dbms are you using?)

Comment: The columns are not indexed

Comment: i'm using SQL Server 2014. I just need to view the closing prices of different currency between certain dates in 1 table.

Comment: _The columns are not indexed_... Then it will take time.

Comment: You'll almost certainly need to index the date then, and make sure that your query is converting the string youre supplying, to a date, rather than converting (?millions) of dates to a string

Comment: OK, i will try. how come without indexing, a normal query without specifying the date will take no time?

Comment: I smell design flaw here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true

once i add primary key, everything works fine

thanks all!